# sender.tag in no set to 1 if user has Login in keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, authentication, keychain

I have create this logic for login button action.my problem if user has login and set sender.tag to loginButtonTag= 1 it will not run this code in "else if sender.tag == loginButtonTag".

```
@IBAction func signedInAction(sender: AnyObject)
{

    if (txtfUsername.text == "" || txtfPassword.text == "") {
         alert()
        return;
    }

    txtfUsername.resignFirstResponder()
    txtfPassword.resignFirstResponder()

    if sender.tag == createLoginButtonTag {
        let hasLoginKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasLoginKey")
        if hasLoginKey == false {                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(self.txtfUsername.text, forKey: "username")
        }


        keychain.set(txtfUsername.text!, forKey:kSecValueData as String)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "hasLoginKey")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        loginButton.tag = 1

        performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
    }
    else if sender.tag == loginButtonTag
    {
        if checkLogin(txtfUsername.text!, password: txtfPassword.text!)
        {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissLogin", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
            alert()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the same button for two cases? Am i right?

Comment: yes, I use same button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following statements:

1. loginButtonTag  really has '1' value
2. Check that during your vc lifecycle any method does not change tag of your loginButton.
3. Check outlet connection for loginButton - it could be nil, so tag is not setted.

There is many reasons, why this snippet don't work.

UPDATE:

if you use the same button, try

`sender.tag = loginButtonTag`

instead of

```
loginButton.tag = 1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sender is type of UIButton, not anyObject.

```
@IBAction func signedInAction(sender: UIButton!)
```